# Setup project: Using dynamic path for adding a file

Tags: visual-studio, macros, windows-installer, vsto

**Summary**

Does `SourcePath` property of a file that is added to a setup project support variables? If yes, How can I ask it to pick the file from the folder corresponding to the current build configuration?

**Detail**

I'm deploying my VSTO add-in using MSI installer, which requires me to include `MyAddin.vsto` and `MyAddin.dll.manifest` files to the application folder. I include them manually using **Add File** command. The problem however is that if I change build configuration from **Debug** to **Release** and build my installer, it will still pick those two files from the **Debug** folder (becuz their paths are hard-coded in the setup project), potentially bundling an old version of the files in the installer. Therefore I want to use some macro/variable that would evaluate to the current build configuration.

The setup project file (`.vdproj`) adds files like this:

```
"SourcePath" = "8:..\\MyAddin\\obj\\Release\\MyAddin.vsto"
```

The path is relative, but the build configuration is hard-coded. I'm looking forward to something like:

```
"SourcePath" = "8:..\\MyAddin\\obj\\[$BUILD_CONFIG]\\MyAddin.vsto"
```

I'm using VS2015 community and .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm interested as I have the same problem. Thanks !

Comment: @Morgane: This is an old post. I can't recall what I ended up with. I think I didn't find a solution then.

Comment: It was a long time ago indeed. I understand, no problem :) I will continue to search in case I find a solution. Thanks anyway !